# syncronise two local SVN checkouts

Tags: svn, mirror, synchronization, local

Quick overview of the problem. 
I have a website that is in SVN and checked out on 2 different servers for load balancing. It's a drupal site and everything besides the assets and files directory is checked out locally on the servers.

Now on an update i have to update the two local checkouts manually.(svn up) This is prone to errors and will provide even more overhead if we decide to add another webserver to the rotation.

**So in short: I have to find a way to automate keeping the 2 local checkouts in sync so i only have to update on 1 server and everything gets synced.**

**Things i have tried:**

- md5 sum of the directory on server 1 and through SSH on server 2 (excluding the .svn directories) using a find command, then executing svn ups on server 2 using the outcome of diff as arguments. It always gives me the same files that are different.

  ssh $TARGET "cd "$SVN_TARGET" && find . -name .svn -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum" >> /tmp/server2.sums

  cd $SVN_SOURCE && find . -name .svn -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum >> /tmp/server1.sums

  diff /tmp/server1.sums /tmp/server2.sums | cut -d"." -f2 | xargs -i ssh $TARGET "su www-data -c 'svn up /dir/to/svn/repo/{} --username \"*******\" --password \"******\"'"
- using svn info and then svn diff with the head revision to give me all the files changed. The problem there is that the local revision id doesn't equal the one of the head revision on the SVN server even when it's up to date.

Any help is much appreciated and excuses for the wall of text :)

Comment: I used a custom post-commit hook script for the svn repo that parses on several words in the path using "/usr/bin/svnlook changed $REPOS -r $REV | sed "s/^....//" " to get the files changed and based on that issueing svn update commands through SSH on the correct servers
Thanks for the help and all the answers, learned some new stuff along the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a crontab entry on each host which runs a script each five minutes? The script could update the svn repository and do whatever post-processing is deemed necessary... .

Or you could have a post-commit hook in subversion trigger the deployment to the two clients... .

Answer (score 0):

How about a control job running in crontab on one of the hosts which does an svn info to determine the revision, that then does a svn update to that revision and at the same time runs an ssh svn update to the same revision on the other host?

Comment: I tried that, the problem there was that the revision id you get from svn info isn't the current revision from the svn repository.

Comment: If you grep for Revsion in the output it will be. Just don't use Last Changed Rev.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're running on linux OSes you may use [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) to sync the datas between the two SVN servers at the block level without worrying about Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) for code deployment. See following tutorials for integration with Drupal: [first](http://tempe.st/2008/07/deploying-drupal-with-capistrano/) and [second](http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/deploying-a-drupal-site-with-git-and-capistrano/).